# Why my map doesn’t center correctly in Minecraft: PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So basically when you make a map it should make its center there where you’re standning but it doesn’t work like this for me, any ideas how to fix it ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maps don't center on you anymore. Instead each map kind of has a set position depending on where you use it. This can be used to make big maps using item frames.